# Spring Boot - How to read properties from multiple custom yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

We are upgrading the spring boot version from 1.3.0.RELEASE to 2.3.12.RELEASE.
As per the old version, yml files were read using the following code snippet

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:/config/myconf-source.yml")
public class MyConfigProperties {

    private String configSource;

    public String getConfigSource() {
        return configSource;
    }

    public void setConfigSource(String configSource) {
        this.configSource = configSource;
    }
}
```

Config files in src/main/resources/config/

```
myconf-source.yml
news-source.yml
conf-mapping.yml
```

Content in myconf-source.yml

```
configSource: "TEST"
```

Corresponding Test Class

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SampleApplication.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:**/config/**")
public class MyConfigPropertiesTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyConfigProperties myConfigProperties;

    @Test
    public void testMyConfigProperties() {
        String config = myConfigProperties.getConfigSource();
        Assert.assertEquals(config, "TEST");
    }
}
```

After changing to the new version, it throws an error `Cannot resolve method 'locations'`.

If I remove `locations` attribute how spring will know the class MyConfigProperties has to read myconf-source.yml

Also while running the test class, NullPointerException is thrown as `myConfigProperties.getConfigSource();`  becomes null.

I have tried various solutions posted but no luck,

Can anyone suggest how to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Configuration` should be used if in that class you define beans with `@Bean`.

If not then remove it from there.

Also `@Configuration` does not make this class a bean to be autowired in the test that you require it to be.
If you want `MyConfigProperties` to be available for autowiring then you also need
`@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyConfigProperties.class)`. This will make sure that this class is available as a spring bean in the application context.

So it would be

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/config/myconf-source.yml")
@ConfigurationProperties()
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyConfigProperties.class)
public class MyConfigProperties {

    private String configSource;

    public String getConfigSource() {
        return configSource;
    }

    public void setConfigSource(String configSource) {
        this.configSource = configSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Can you share how the test should look like?

Comment: IMO it should work as it is, have you tried? Make sure that all the yaml files are both in `src/main/resources` as well in `test/resources`

Answer (score 0):

You can use @PropertySource annotation to read the yml file , you can read the below article :

https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful